# About changing the UIAlertview GUI

Tags: ios, delegates, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

Yesterday I use UIAlertViewDelegate...

What is the difference between them :

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Comment: the time they are called. Will gets called before did and clicked gets called before both.

Comment: You would have found the answer if you had Cmd + clicked on the `UIAlertViewDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

this method called when after you clicked on button and before dismissing the alertView.

`-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

this method called at the time you clicked on button.

`-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

this method called when after you clicked on button and after dismissing the alertView.

`-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`